# Getting rid of "X Google enrollment" in Android 11? since I don't use Assistant

Tags: notifications, google, google-play-services, google-assistant, android-11

Since I have a new phone with Android 11, every now and then I see a notification about "X Google enrollment" whatever that may be.
Upon searching around I see it's nothing to worry about, it's just part of Google Assistant.

However I don't use Google Assistent, I have turned it off completely. Yet this "X Google enrollment" is still happening.

Is there I way to get rid of it? And I mean not just the notification (sure, I can disable that) but the thing itself. I'd rather not want any unnecessary processes to start or run at all.

Comment: [Wait for Google to fix it....they are aware of this issue](https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/59569398?hl=en) ; [Also see what it means](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/09/18/this-is-what-that-google-x-enrollment-notification-on-your-phone-means/)

Comment: I don't see that on my Pixel 4a, so your device needs to wait for the fix or else, root your device and freeze/uninstall Google assistant